# Trying to get Django-Hitcount module working on Mezzanine

Tags: python, django, mezzanine

I think I have narrowed it down to Disqus comments.  I am trying to count Blog article hits. I am using Mezzanine and the built in blog app because the app supports Disqus comments.  However, when I enable Disqus comments the django_hitcount app stops working even though the 2 should not really be related.  I get a `http 403 error` when django_hitcount module tries to `POST` data to it's hitcounter using Javascript.

When I log in as admin it works but I want it to work with anonymous visitors.  So it is related to Mezzanine permissions and Mezzanine comment settings somehow.  To summarize again, it always works with django comments enabled.  Does not work with Disqus comments enabled and django comments disabled unless logged in as admin.

I am not trying to do anything with comments.  It has something to do with how django_hitcount module works internally.  It doesn't seem to like when Disqus comments are enabled, corresponding to django comments disabled, and you are not logged in.

I think I have narrowed it down to the following line in hitcount_tags.py using the python pbg debugger.
https://github.com/thornomad/django-hitcount/blob/master/hitcount/templatetags/hitcount_tags.py

```
ctype, object_pk = get_target_ctype_pk(context, self.object_expr)
```

And this is the function it uses.

```
def get_target_ctype_pk(context, object_expr):
# I don't really understand how this is working, but I took it from the
# comment app in django.contrib and the removed it from the Node.

try:
    obj = object_expr.resolve(context)
except template.VariableDoesNotExist:
    return None, None
return ContentType.objects.get_for_model(obj), obj.pk
```

I can't figure out what this is doing and was hoping someone can explain it. 
https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/comments/templatetags/comments.py

Also possibly why it fails when Mezzanine disqus comments are enabled and the user is not logged in.